# Juju Openstack bundle: Can't launch an instance

Tags: juju, maas, openstack

```
Deployed bundle:~makyo/openstack/2/openstack, on top of 7 physical boxes and 3 virtual ones. After changing vip_iface strings to point to right devices, e.g., br0 instead of eth0, and defining "/mnt/loopback|30G", in Cinder's block-device string, am able to navigate through openstack dashboard, error free. Following http://docs.openstack.org/grizzly/openstack-compute/install/apt/content/running-an-instance.html instructions, attempted to launch cirros 0.3.1 image; however, novalist shows the instance in error state. 
ubuntu@node7:~$ nova --debug boot --flavor 1 --image 28bed1bc-bc1c-4533-beee-8e0428ad40dd --key_name key2 --security_group default cirros
REQ: curl -i http://keyStone.IP:5000/v2.0/tokens -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "User-Agent: python-novaclient" -d '{"auth": {"tenantName": "admin", "passwordCredentials": {"username": "admin", "password": "openstack"}}}'

INFO (connectionpool:191) Starting new HTTP connection (1): keyStone.IP
DEBUG (connectionpool:283) "POST /v2.0/tokens HTTP/1.1" 200 None
RESP: [200] {'date': 'Tue, 10 Jun 2014 00:01:02 GMT', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'vary': 'X-Auth-Token', 'content-type': 'application/json'}
RESP BODY: {"access": {"token": {"expires": "2014-06-11T00:01:02Z", "id": "3eefa1837d984426a633fe09259a1534", "tenant": {"description": "Created by Juju", "enabled": true, "id": "08cff06d13b74492b780d9ceed699239", "name": "admin"}}, "serviceCatalog": [{"endpoints": [{"adminURL": "http://nova.cloud.controller:8774/v1.1/08cff06d13b74492b780d9ceed699239", "region": "RegionOne", "internalURL": "http://nova.cloud.controller:8774/v1.1/08cff06d13b74492b780d9ceed699239", "publicURL": "http://nova.cloud.controller:8774/v1.1/08cff06d13b74492b780d9ceed699239"}], "endpoints_links": [], "type": "compute", "name": "nova"}, {"endpoints": [{"adminURL": "http://nova.cloud.controller:9696", "region": "RegionOne", "internalURL": "http://nova.cloud.controller:9696", "publicURL": "http://nova.cloud.controller:9696"}], "endpoints_links": [], "type": "network", "name": "quantum"}, {"endpoints": [{"adminURL": "http://nova.cloud.controller:3333", "region": "RegionOne", "internalURL": "http://nova.cloud.controller:3333", "publicURL": "http://nova.cloud.controller:3333"}], "endpoints_links": [], "type": "s3", "name": "s3"}, {"endpoints": [{"adminURL": "http://i.p.s.36:9292", "region": "RegionOne", "internalURL": "http://i.p.s.36:9292", "publicURL": "http://i.p.s.36:9292"}], "endpoints_links": [], "type": "image", "name": "glance"}, {"endpoints": [{"adminURL": "http://i.p.s.39:8776/v1/08cff06d13b74492b780d9ceed699239", "region": "RegionOne", "internalURL": "http://i.p.s.39:8776/v1/08cff06d13b74492b780d9ceed699239", "publicURL": "http://i.p.s.39:8776/v1/08cff06d13b74492b780d9ceed699239"}], "endpoints_links": [], "type": "volume", "name": "cinder"}, {"endpoints": [{"adminURL": "http://nova.cloud.controller:8773/services/Cloud", "region": "RegionOne", "internalURL": "http://nova.cloud.controller:8773/services/Cloud", "publicURL": "http://nova.cloud.controller:8773/services/Cloud"}], "endpoints_links": [], "type": "ec2", "name": "ec2"}, {"endpoints": [{"adminURL": "http://keyStone.IP:35357/v2.0", "region": "RegionOne", "internalURL": "http://keyStone.IP:5000/v2.0", "publicURL": "http://i.p.s.44:5000/v2.0"}], "endpoints_links": [], "type": "identity", "name": "keystone"}], "user": {"username": "admin", "roles_links": [], "id": "b3730a52a32e40f0a9500440d1ef1c7d", "roles": [{"id": "e020001eb9a049f4a16540238ab158aa", "name": "Admin"}, {"id": "b84fbff4d5554d53bbbffdaad66b56cb", "name": "KeystoneServiceAdmin"}, {"id": "129c8b49d42b4f0796109aaef2069aa9", "name": "KeystoneAdmin"}], "name": "admin"}}}


REQ: curl -i http://nova.cloud.controller:8774/v1.1/08cff06d13b74492b780d9ceed699239/images/28bed1bc-bc1c-4533-beee-8e0428ad40dd -X GET -H "X-Auth-Project-Id: admin" -H "User-Agent: python-novaclient" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "X-Auth-Token: 3eefa1837d984426a633fe09259a1534"

INFO (connectionpool:191) Starting new HTTP connection (1): nova.cloud.controller
DEBUG (connectionpool:283) "GET /v1.1/08cff06d13b74492b780d9ceed699239/images/28bed1bc-bc1c-4533-beee-8e0428ad40dd HTTP/1.1" 200 719
RESP: [200] {'date': 'Tue, 10 Jun 2014 00:01:03 GMT', 'x-compute-request-id': 'req-7f3459f8-d3d5-47f1-97a3-8407a4419a69', 'content-type': 'application/json', 'content-length': '719'}
RESP BODY: {"image": {"status": "ACTIVE", "updated": "2014-06-09T22:17:54Z", "links": [{"href": "http://nova.cloud.controller:8774/v1.1/08cff06d13b74492b780d9ceed699239/images/28bed1bc-bc1c-4533-beee-8e0428ad40dd", "rel": "self"}, {"href": "http://nova.cloud.controller:8774/08cff06d13b74492b780d9ceed699239/images/28bed1bc-bc1c-4533-beee-8e0428ad40dd", "rel": "bookmark"}, {"href": "http://External.Public.Port:9292/08cff06d13b74492b780d9ceed699239/images/28bed1bc-bc1c-4533-beee-8e0428ad40dd", "type": "application/vnd.openstack.image", "rel": "alternate"}], "id": "28bed1bc-bc1c-4533-beee-8e0428ad40dd", "OS-EXT-IMG-SIZE:size": 13147648, "name": "Cirros 0.3.1", "created": "2014-06-09T22:17:54Z", "minDisk": 0, "progress": 100, "minRam": 0, "metadata": {}}}


REQ: curl -i http://nova.cloud.controller:8774/v1.1/08cff06d13b74492b780d9ceed699239/flavors/1 -X GET -H "X-Auth-Project-Id: admin" -H "User-Agent: python-novaclient" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "X-Auth-Token: 3eefa1837d984426a633fe09259a1534"

INFO (connectionpool:191) Starting new HTTP connection (1): nova.cloud.controller
DEBUG (connectionpool:283) "GET /v1.1/08cff06d13b74492b780d9ceed699239/flavors/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 418
RESP: [200] {'date': 'Tue, 10 Jun 2014 00:01:04 GMT', 'x-compute-request-id': 'req-2c153110-6969-4f3a-b51c-8f1a6ce75bee', 'content-type': 'application/json', 'content-length': '418'}
RESP BODY: {"flavor": {"name": "m1.tiny", "links": [{"href": "http://nova.cloud.controller:8774/v1.1/08cff06d13b74492b780d9ceed699239/flavors/1", "rel": "self"}, {"href": "http://nova.cloud.controller:8774/08cff06d13b74492b780d9ceed699239/flavors/1", "rel": "bookmark"}], "ram": 512, "OS-FLV-DISABLED:disabled": false, "vcpus": 1, "swap": "", "os-flavor-access:is_public": true, "rxtx_factor": 1.0, "OS-FLV-EXT-DATA:ephemeral": 0, "disk": 0, "id": "1"}}


REQ: curl -i http://nova.cloud.controller:8774/v1.1/08cff06d13b74492b780d9ceed699239/servers -X POST -H "X-Auth-Project-Id: admin" -H "User-Agent: python-novaclient" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "X-Auth-Token: 3eefa1837d984426a633fe09259a1534" -d '{"server": {"name": "cirros", "imageRef": "28bed1bc-bc1c-4533-beee-8e0428ad40dd", "key_name": "key2", "flavorRef": "1", "max_count": 1, "min_count": 1, "security_groups": [{"name": "default"}]}}'

INFO (connectionpool:191) Starting new HTTP connection (1): nova.cloud.controller
DEBUG (connectionpool:283) "POST /v1.1/08cff06d13b74492b780d9ceed699239/servers HTTP/1.1" 202 436
RESP: [202] {'date': 'Tue, 10 Jun 2014 00:01:05 GMT', 'x-compute-request-id': 'req-41e53086-6454-4efb-bb35-a30dc2c780be', 'content-type': 'application/json', 'location': 'http://nova.cloud.controller:8774/v1.1/08cff06d13b74492b780d9ceed699239/servers/2eb5e3ad-3044-41c1-bbb7-10f398f83e43', 'content-length': '436'}
RESP BODY: {"server": {"security_groups": [{"name": "default"}], "OS-DCF:diskConfig": "MANUAL", "id": "2eb5e3ad-3044-41c1-bbb7-10f398f83e43", "links": [{"href": "http://nova.cloud.controller:8774/v1.1/08cff06d13b74492b780d9ceed699239/servers/2eb5e3ad-3044-41c1-bbb7-10f398f83e43", "rel": "self"}, {"href": "http://nova.cloud.controller:8774/08cff06d13b74492b780d9ceed699239/servers/2eb5e3ad-3044-41c1-bbb7-10f398f83e43", "rel": "bookmark"}], "adminPass": "oFRbvRqif2C8"}}


REQ: curl -i http://nova.cloud.controller:8774/v1.1/08cff06d13b74492b780d9ceed699239/servers/2eb5e3ad-3044-41c1-bbb7-10f398f83e43 -X GET -H "X-Auth-Project-Id: admin" -H "User-Agent: python-novaclient" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "X-Auth-Token: 3eefa1837d984426a633fe09259a1534"

INFO (connectionpool:191) Starting new HTTP connection (1): nova.cloud.controller
DEBUG (connectionpool:283) "GET /v1.1/08cff06d13b74492b780d9ceed699239/servers/2eb5e3ad-3044-41c1-bbb7-10f398f83e43 HTTP/1.1" 200 1349
RESP: [200] {'date': 'Tue, 10 Jun 2014 00:01:05 GMT', 'x-compute-request-id': 'req-d91d0858-7030-469d-8e55-40e05e4d00fd', 'content-type': 'application/json', 'content-length': '1349'}
RESP BODY: {"server": {"status": "BUILD", "updated": "2014-06-10T00:01:05Z", "hostId": "", "OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:host": null, "addresses": {}, "links": [{"href": "http://nova.cloud.controller:8774/v1.1/08cff06d13b74492b780d9ceed699239/servers/2eb5e3ad-3044-41c1-bbb7-10f398f83e43", "rel": "self"}, {"href": "http://nova.cloud.controller:8774/08cff06d13b74492b780d9ceed699239/servers/2eb5e3ad-3044-41c1-bbb7-10f398f83e43", "rel": "bookmark"}], "key_name": "key2", "image": {"id": "28bed1bc-bc1c-4533-beee-8e0428ad40dd", "links": [{"href": "http://nova.cloud.controller:8774/08cff06d13b74492b780d9ceed699239/images/28bed1bc-bc1c-4533-beee-8e0428ad40dd", "rel": "bookmark"}]}, "OS-EXT-STS:task_state": "scheduling", "OS-EXT-STS:vm_state": "building", "OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:instance_name": "instance-00000004", "OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:hypervisor_hostname": null, "flavor": {"id": "1", "links": [{"href": "http://nova.cloud.controller:8774/08cff06d13b74492b780d9ceed699239/flavors/1", "rel": "bookmark"}]}, "id": "2eb5e3ad-3044-41c1-bbb7-10f398f83e43", "security_groups": [{"name": "default"}], "OS-EXT-AZ:availability_zone": "nova", "user_id": "b3730a52a32e40f0a9500440d1ef1c7d", "name": "cirros", "created": "2014-06-10T00:01:04Z", "tenant_id": "08cff06d13b74492b780d9ceed699239", "OS-DCF:diskConfig": "MANUAL", "accessIPv4": "", "accessIPv6": "", "progress": 0, "OS-EXT-STS:power_state": 0, "config_drive": "", "metadata": {}}}


REQ: curl -i http://nova.cloud.controller:8774/v1.1/08cff06d13b74492b780d9ceed699239/flavors/1 -X GET -H "X-Auth-Project-Id: admin" -H "User-Agent: python-novaclient" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "X-Auth-Token: 3eefa1837d984426a633fe09259a1534"

INFO (connectionpool:191) Starting new HTTP connection (1): nova.cloud.controller
DEBUG (connectionpool:283) "GET /v1.1/08cff06d13b74492b780d9ceed699239/flavors/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 418
RESP: [200] {'date': 'Tue, 10 Jun 2014 00:01:05 GMT', 'x-compute-request-id': 'req-896c0120-1102-4408-9e09-cd628f2dd699', 'content-type': 'application/json', 'content-length': '418'}
RESP BODY: {"flavor": {"name": "m1.tiny", "links": [{"href": "http://nova.cloud.controller:8774/v1.1/08cff06d13b74492b780d9ceed699239/flavors/1", "rel": "self"}, {"href": "http://nova.cloud.controller:8774/08cff06d13b74492b780d9ceed699239/flavors/1", "rel": "bookmark"}], "ram": 512, "OS-FLV-DISABLED:disabled": false, "vcpus": 1, "swap": "", "os-flavor-access:is_public": true, "rxtx_factor": 1.0, "OS-FLV-EXT-DATA:ephemeral": 0, "disk": 0, "id": "1"}}


REQ: curl -i http://nova.cloud.controller:8774/v1.1/08cff06d13b74492b780d9ceed699239/images/28bed1bc-bc1c-4533-beee-8e0428ad40dd -X GET -H "X-Auth-Project-Id: admin" -H "User-Agent: python-novaclient" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "X-Auth-Token: 3eefa1837d984426a633fe09259a1534"

INFO (connectionpool:191) Starting new HTTP connection (1): nova.cloud.controller
DEBUG (connectionpool:283) "GET /v1.1/08cff06d13b74492b780d9ceed699239/images/28bed1bc-bc1c-4533-beee-8e0428ad40dd HTTP/1.1" 200 719
RESP: [200] {'date': 'Tue, 10 Jun 2014 00:01:05 GMT', 'x-compute-request-id': 'req-454e9651-c247-4d31-8049-6b254de050ae', 'content-type': 'application/json', 'content-length': '719'}
RESP BODY: {"image": {"status": "ACTIVE", "updated": "2014-06-09T22:17:54Z", "links": [{"href": "http://nova.cloud.controller:8774/v1.1/08cff06d13b74492b780d9ceed699239/images/28bed1bc-bc1c-4533-beee-8e0428ad40dd", "rel": "self"}, {"href": "http://nova.cloud.controller:8774/08cff06d13b74492b780d9ceed699239/images/28bed1bc-bc1c-4533-beee-8e0428ad40dd", "rel": "bookmark"}, {"href": "http://External.Public.Port:9292/08cff06d13b74492b780d9ceed699239/images/28bed1bc-bc1c-4533-beee-8e0428ad40dd", "type": "application/vnd.openstack.image", "rel": "alternate"}], "id": "28bed1bc-bc1c-4533-beee-8e0428ad40dd", "OS-EXT-IMG-SIZE:size": 13147648, "name": "Cirros 0.3.1", "created": "2014-06-09T22:17:54Z", "minDisk": 0, "progress": 100, "minRam": 0, "metadata": {}}}

+-------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| Property                            | Value                                |
+-------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| OS-EXT-STS:task_state               | scheduling                           |
| image                               | Cirros 0.3.1                         |
| OS-EXT-STS:vm_state                 | building                             |
| OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:instance_name       | instance-00000004                    |
| flavor                              | m1.tiny                              |
| id                                  | 2eb5e3ad-3044-41c1-bbb7-10f398f83e43 |
| security_groups                     | [{u'name': u'default'}]              |
| user_id                             | b3730a52a32e40f0a9500440d1ef1c7d     |
| OS-DCF:diskConfig                   | MANUAL                               |
| accessIPv4                          |                                      |
| accessIPv6                          |                                      |
| progress                            | 0                                    |
| OS-EXT-STS:power_state              | 0                                    |
| OS-EXT-AZ:availability_zone         | nova                                 |
| config_drive                        |                                      |
| status                              | BUILD                                |
| updated                             | 2014-06-10T00:01:05Z                 |
| hostId                              |                                      |
| OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:host                | None                                 |
| key_name                            | key2                                 |
| OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:hypervisor_hostname | None                                 |
| name                                | cirros                               |
| adminPass                           | oFRbvRqif2C8                         |
| tenant_id                           | 08cff06d13b74492b780d9ceed699239     |
| created                             | 2014-06-10T00:01:04Z                 |
| metadata                            | {}                                   |
+-------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
ubuntu@node7:~$

ubuntu@node7:~$ nova list
+--------------------------------------+--------+--------+----------+
| ID                                   | Name   | Status | Networks |
+--------------------------------------+--------+--------+----------+
| 2eb5e3ad-3044-41c1-bbb7-10f398f83e43 | cirros | ERROR  |          |
+--------------------------------------+--------+--------+----------+
ubuntu@node7:~$ 


 var/log/nova/nova-compute.log shows the following error:
...
2014-06-10 00:01:06.048 AUDIT nova.compute.claims [req-41e53086-6454-4efb-bb35-a30dc2c780be b3730a52a32e40f0a9500440d1ef1c7d 08cff06d13b74492b780d9ceed699239] [instance: 2eb5e3ad-3044-41c1-bbb7-10f398f83e43] Attempting claim: memory 512 MB, disk 0 GB, VCPUs 1
2014-06-10 00:01:06.049 AUDIT nova.compute.claims [req-41e53086-6454-4efb-bb35-a30dc2c780be b3730a52a32e40f0a9500440d1ef1c7d 08cff06d13b74492b780d9ceed699239] [instance: 2eb5e3ad-3044-41c1-bbb7-10f398f83e43] Total Memory: 3885 MB, used: 512 MB
2014-06-10 00:01:06.049 AUDIT nova.compute.claims [req-41e53086-6454-4efb-bb35-a30dc2c780be b3730a52a32e40f0a9500440d1ef1c7d 08cff06d13b74492b780d9ceed699239] [instance: 2eb5e3ad-3044-41c1-bbb7-10f398f83e43] Memory limit: 5827 MB, free: 5315 MB
2014-06-10 00:01:06.049 AUDIT nova.compute.claims [req-41e53086-6454-4efb-bb35-a30dc2c780be b3730a52a32e40f0a9500440d1ef1c7d 08cff06d13b74492b780d9ceed699239] [instance: 2eb5e3ad-3044-41c1-bbb7-10f398f83e43] Total Disk: 146 GB, used: 0 GB
2014-06-10 00:01:06.050 AUDIT nova.compute.claims [req-41e53086-6454-4efb-bb35-a30dc2c780be b3730a52a32e40f0a9500440d1ef1c7d 08cff06d13b74492b780d9ceed699239] [instance: 2eb5e3ad-3044-41c1-bbb7-10f398f83e43] Disk limit not specified, defaulting to unlimited
2014-06-10 00:01:06.050 AUDIT nova.compute.claims [req-41e53086-6454-4efb-bb35-a30dc2c780be b3730a52a32e40f0a9500440d1ef1c7d 08cff06d13b74492b780d9ceed699239] [instance: 2eb5e3ad-3044-41c1-bbb7-10f398f83e43] Total CPU: 2 VCPUs, used: 0 VCPUs
2014-06-10 00:01:06.050 AUDIT nova.compute.claims [req-41e53086-6454-4efb-bb35-a30dc2c780be b3730a52a32e40f0a9500440d1ef1c7d 08cff06d13b74492b780d9ceed699239] [instance: 2eb5e3ad-3044-41c1-bbb7-10f398f83e43] CPU limit not specified, defaulting to unlimited
2014-06-10 00:01:06.051 AUDIT nova.compute.claims [req-41e53086-6454-4efb-bb35-a30dc2c780be b3730a52a32e40f0a9500440d1ef1c7d 08cff06d13b74492b780d9ceed699239] [instance: 2eb5e3ad-3044-41c1-bbb7-10f398f83e43] Claim successful
2014-06-10 00:01:06.963 WARNING nova.network.quantumv2.api [req-41e53086-6454-4efb-bb35-a30dc2c780be b3730a52a32e40f0a9500440d1ef1c7d 08cff06d13b74492b780d9ceed699239] [instance: 2eb5e3ad-3044-41c1-bbb7-10f398f83e43] No network configured!
2014-06-10 00:01:08.347 ERROR nova.compute.manager [req-41e53086-6454-4efb-bb35-a30dc2c780be b3730a52a32e40f0a9500440d1ef1c7d 08cff06d13b74492b780d9ceed699239] [instance: 2eb5e3ad-3044-41c1-bbb7-10f398f83e43] Instance failed to spawn
2014-06-10 00:01:08.347 32223 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 2eb5e3ad-3044-41c1-bbb7-10f398f83e43] Traceback (most recent call last):
2014-06-10 00:01:08.347 32223 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 2eb5e3ad-3044-41c1-bbb7-10f398f83e43]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 1118, in _spawn
2014-06-10 00:01:08.347 32223 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 2eb5e3ad-3044-41c1-bbb7-10f398f83e43]     self._legacy_nw_info(network_info),
2014-06-10 00:01:08.347 32223 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 2eb5e3ad-3044-41c1-bbb7-10f398f83e43]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 703, in _legacy_nw_info
2014-06-10 00:01:08.347 32223 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 2eb5e3ad-3044-41c1-bbb7-10f398f83e43]     network_info = network_info.legacy()
2014-06-10 00:01:08.347 32223 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 2eb5e3ad-3044-41c1-bbb7-10f398f83e43] AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'legacy'
2014-06-10 00:01:08.347 32223 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 2eb5e3ad-3044-41c1-bbb7-10f398f83e43] 
2014-06-10 00:01:08.919 AUDIT nova.compute.manager [req-41e53086-6454-4efb-bb35-a30dc2c780be b3730a52a32e40f0a9500440d1ef1c7d 08cff06d13b74492b780d9ceed699239] [instance: 2eb5e3ad-3044-41c1-bbb7-10f398f83e43] Terminating instance
2014-06-10 00:01:09.712 32223 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.driver [-] [instance: 2eb5e3ad-3044-41c1-bbb7-10f398f83e43] During wait destroy, instance disappeared.
2014-06-10 00:01:09.718 INFO nova.virt.libvirt.firewall [req-41e53086-6454-4efb-bb35-a30dc2c780be b3730a52a32e40f0a9500440d1ef1c7d 08cff06d13b74492b780d9ceed699239] [instance: 2eb5e3ad-3044-41c1-bbb7-10f398f83e43] Attempted to unfilter instance which is not filtered
2014-06-10 00:01:09.719 INFO nova.virt.libvirt.driver [req-41e53086-6454-4efb-bb35-a30dc2c780be b3730a52a32e40f0a9500440d1ef1c7d 08cff06d13b74492b780d9ceed699239] [instance: 2eb5e3ad-3044-41c1-bbb7-10f398f83e43] Deleting instance files /var/lib/nova/instances/2eb5e3ad-3044-41c1-bbb7-10f398f83e43
2014-06-10 00:01:10.044 ERROR nova.compute.manager [req-41e53086-6454-4efb-bb35-a30dc2c780be b3730a52a32e40f0a9500440d1ef1c7d 08cff06d13b74492b780d9ceed699239] [instance: 2eb5e3ad-3044-41c1-bbb7-10f398f83e43] Error: ['Traceback (most recent call last):\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 864, in _run_instance\n    set_access_ip=set_access_ip)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 1123, in _spawn\n    LOG.exception(_(\'Instance failed to spawn\'), instance=instance)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 24, in __exit__\n    self.gen.next()\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 1118, in _spawn\n    self._legacy_nw_info(network_info),\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 703, in _legacy_nw_info\n    network_info = network_info.legacy()\n', "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'legacy'\n"]
2014-06-10 00:01:40.951 32223 AUDIT nova.compute.resource_tracker [-] Auditing locally available compute resources
2014-06-10 00:01:41.072 32223 AUDIT nova.compute.resource_tracker [-] Free ram (MB): 2861
2014-06-10 00:01:41.072 32223 AUDIT nova.compute.resource_tracker [-] Free disk (GB): 146
2014-06-10 00:01:41.073 32223 AUDIT nova.compute.resource_tracker [-] Free VCPUS: 1
2014-06-10 00:01:41.262 32223 INFO nova.compute.resource_tracker [-] Compute_service record updated for node5:node5.maas
```

...
Can't seem to find any entries in quantum.conf related to "legacy". Any help would be appreciated.
Cheers,

Comment: aaaaaahhh! Please use http://pastebin.ubuntu.com and edit your question so we can read it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that Quantum charm did not create any of the required networks, sub-nets, or routers. Had to create them manually, following https://wiki.debian.org/OpenStackHowto/Quantum, after which I was able to boot, create, and login to a cirros instance. I did upgrade on all the charms, e.g., quantum, right now, sits at cs:precise/quantum-gateway-20. Will do some further experimentations with ext-port, external-network-id, etc. (Though, so far nothing tangible.)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the bundle ~makyo/openstack is a demonstration bundle only.  The problem with deploying a bundle for OpenStack is that the Ceph charm has a write-once config option.  Given that, this bundle has been removed from the charm store.  For more information on deploying OpenStack with Juju, there is a video available here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V2H3fat0K5w

Comment: Not sure if we are referring to the same bundle. As it does not include Ceph charm and is still available in the charm store. I did look at the clip that you are referring to, and was hoping that bundles would give a more stable performance. Will revisit.

Comment: Just went through the clip once more, and its components and topology are identical to makyo's bundle. (With the notable difference that makyo's nova-cloud-controller charm does not have the conf-ext-net field.) Given that failure is initiated due to lack of networking, this could be a clue.